# If $u$ is harmonic, is $|Du|^2$ continuous up to boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Suppose $u \in C^2(B_1)$ is harmonic in $B_1$, the ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$.

We can show that $\Delta (|Du|^2) \geq 0$, so $|Du|^2$ is subharmonic.

Is $|Du|^2$ continuous up to boundary, i.e. is $|Du|^2 \in C(\overline{B_1})$? How to prove this? As we only know the partial derivatives are continuous **inside** $B_1$.

If yes, I can use a maximum principle to estimate $Du$ in $B_1$ in terms of $Du$ on $\partial B_1$.

To be clear, the version of the max principle I am trying to use is: suppose $u$ is subharmonic and $u $ is in $C(\overline{B})$ then $\sup_B u \leq \sup_{\partial B} u$

Comment: Ok, I don't know. But if you want to estimate $Du$ in the ball, you can use that it is harmonic itself. So the maximum principle applies to each of its components. It can well be that I am overlooking something, in which case I would love to know what that is

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro it probably is something simple, but what do you mean that Du is harmonic? Du is a vector function...?

Comment: I am trying to use the max principle, but it requires continuous up to boundary

Comment: I mean that each entry of $Du$ is harmonic; that is, $\partial_{x_1}u, \partial_{x_2}u, \ldots$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ah ok but it still wouldn't allow me to use the max principle

Comment: I am not the downvoter. Frankly I do not understand the unexplained downvote, a practice which I don't agree with. ANYWAY: The estimate $\lvert Du(x)\rvert^2\le \sup_{\partial B} \lvert Du(x)\rvert^2$ is true. The problem is that the right-hand side might be $\infty$, as the accepted answer shows. Proof: Since the functions $\partial_{x_j} u$ are all harmonic, the function $\sum_j (\partial_{x_j}u)^2=\lvert Du\rvert^2$ is subharmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we won't necessarily have continuity up to the boundary. Take $\Phi(\mathbf x) = \frac{-1}{2\pi} \ln|\mathbf x|$ to be the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation in $\mathbb R^2$. Since it is the fundamental solution $-\Delta \Phi(\mathbf x) = \delta(\mathbf x)$ and it is harmonic on any open set that excludes zero. We can shift it by $\mathbf e_1 = (1,0)$ to get a counter-example to the claim. We have $\Phi(\mathbf x - \mathbf e_1)$ is harmonic on $B_1$ but $|D\Phi(\mathbf x -\mathbf e_1)|^2$ is not continuous at $(1,0)\in\partial B_1$.